# Does redis store duplicate values or just a pointer / reference

Tags: redis

If two distinct keys have the same value (and say the value is large) does redis store the value twice or will it use a pointer / reference. The way git does ?

Answer (score 2):

Redis stores them as two independent key-value pairs.

If you want to remove the duplication, you have to build an index from multiple keys to a shared value by yourself.